# Fail to update, data in the datatable clicking the save button

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

[image]

[image]

[image]

script

```
  function startEdit(obj) {            
            $(".inline-view").show();
            $(".inline-edit").hide();
            $(obj).closest('tr').find("td .inline-view").hide();
            $(obj).closest('tr').find("td .inline-edit").show();
            $("#customerGrid_wrapper").css("overflow-x", "auto");
        }
 $(function () {
            $(".savebutton").click(function () {
               // alert("Im Here");
                $(".inline-edit").hide();
                $(".inline-view").show();


                var tr = $(this).closest('tr').find("td .inline_edit");
                var FirstName = tr.find("item_FirstName").val();
                var MiddleName = tr.find("item_MiddleName").val();
                var LastName = tr.find("item_LastName").val();
                var Gender = tr.find("item_Gender").val();
                var CompanyName = tr.find("item.CompanyName").val();
                var Address = tr.find("item_Address").val();
                var City = tr.find("item_City").val();
                var Country = tr.find("item_Country").val();
                var Email = tr.find("item_Email").val();
                var Phone = tr.find("item_Phone").val();
                var CustomerId = $(this).data("customerid");

                $(this).closest('tr').find("td .first_name").text("FirstName");
                $(this).closest('tr').find("td .middle_name").text("MiddleName");
                $(this).closest('tr').find("td .last_name").text("LastName");
                $(this).closest('tr').find("td .gender").text("Gender");
                $(this).closest('tr').find("td .company_name").text("CompanyName");
                $(this).closest('tr').find("td .address").text("Address");
                $(this).closest('tr').find("td .city").text("City");
                $(this).closest('tr').find("td .country").text("Country");
                $(this).closest('tr').find("td .email").text("Email");
                $(this).closest('tr').find("td .phone").text("Phone");

                var CustomerModel = {
                    CustomerId: CustomerId,
                    FirstName: FirstName,
                    MiddleName: MiddleName,
                    LastName: LastName,
                    Gender: Gender,
                    CompanyName: CompanyName,
                    Address: Address,
                    City: City,
                    Country: Country,
                    Email: Email,
                    Phone: Phone
                };

                $.ajax({                     
                    url: '/Customers/Edit/',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(CustomerModel),
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data, status) {
                        console.log('Updating data is successful');
                    },
                    error: function (e,s,t) {
                        console.log(t.getMessage);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

View

```
<table id="customerGrid" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomerId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </th>


<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.CustomerId)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="inline-view first_name">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                </div>
                <div class="inline-edit" style='display:none;'>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                </div>
            </td>
}
<td>
    <div class="inline-view">
        <button type="button" class="editBtn" onclick='startEdit(this);'>Edit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inline-edit" style="display:none;">
         <input class="savebutton"  id="saveBtn" type="button" value="Save" data-customerid="@item.CustomerId" />
         <button type="button" id="cancelBtn" onclick='cancelEdit(); return false;'>Cancel</button>
   </div>
</td>
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Customers model)
        {
             try
            {
                CustomerActions customer = new CustomerActions();
                if(ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                   bool isSuccess =  customer.UpdateCustomer(model);
                    if(isSuccess)
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = "Updated successfully.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = "Not updated successfully.";
                    }
                    customer.FetchCutomers();
                }
                return Json(new { customer }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            } 

        }
```

I'm using Customer datatable to perform edit/delete actions. When I try to update the data the variable binding into the table and it fail to go the edit method in the controller.
I attached the images to get clear idea what I'm struggling with. Can someone explain why this is happening, and how to fix it please? Thanks.

Comment: `onclick='startEdit(this);'` - Where do you define this `startEdit` function?  What specifically are you expecting to happen when you click the Edit button and why?

Comment: @David I added the startEdit funtion in my question. When I click the edit button, the respective row become editable and and I hide edit button and show the Save and Cancel button. The save button update the changes in the DB and and fetch the updated data from the DB and bind the same in the View.

Comment: Where specifically is this failing?  That is, when you click the Edit button what specifically happens?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console (before or after clicking the Edit button)?  When you use the browser's script debugger and place a debugging breakpoint in the `startEdit` function, is that function invoked by the button?  What happens in the debugger?